# PHP escapeshellcmd is escaping Turkish language characters

Tags: python, php

I run python script from my php file with `shell_exec` function. I have to pass some parameters to script and I using `escapeshellcmd` for preparing command. However when I pass args which contain Turkish characters (Ğ,ğ,Ü,ü,Ş,ş,İ,i,Ö,ö,Ç,ç) escapeshellcmd escape that characters.

Example:

```
$args = "--title Günaydın --title İyi Günler";
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python -W ignore test.py '.$args);
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

**Expected output:** /usr/bin/python -W ignore test.py --title Günaydın --title İyi Günler

**Actual Output:** /usr/bin/python -W ignore test.py --title Gnaydn --title yi Gnler

How can I use escapeshellcmd with Turkish characters?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://tio.run/##TcxLCsIwFIXh@V1FKIHWQd1AFYcuo4TkYgp5XJK02F3p3JndV2wjRac/5zukKefThTQBcBFukZ1Z1bZpSAbZ9f1yYlbL07E9LY95KN1gqDrg0lsrnFoVRikIo0ZjpFVNjVJ7Vh/L6aEDmETo1Wip2c0WuR8TjWnlBfZ4R/k/@KHvcDOQ8wc)

Answer (score 0):

`escapeshellcmd` strips non-ASCII characters from a string by default. Try with `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");` before.